# Excel replace multiple sets of value with single value

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Consider a Excel sheet column with the following distinct values :

```
Dell Latitude 4580
Dell Latitude 1520
Lenovo 820
Acer 220
Acer 530
Acer 230
```

I would like "map" these values to more common groups, for example

```
Dell Latitude 4580 -> Laptop 2-core
Dell Latitude 1520 -> Laptop 4-core
Lenovo 820 -> Desktop 2-core
Acer 220 -> Desktop 2-core
Acer 530 -> Desktop 4-core
Acer 230 -> Laptop 4-core
```

How can I do that efficiently with Excel formula ? At the moment I am at nested substitute : `substitute(substitute(cell; "Dell Latitude 4580"; "Laptop 2-core");"Dell Latitude 1520";"Laptop 4-core")...`

But this is just ugly and not so scalable. Any idea ?

Comment: Put you input and desired outputs in a table and use Vlookup to return the desired output.

Comment: My bad, I forgot the Vlookup. Can someone explain the downvote please ?

Comment: My guess, as it was not me, is that you are asking for vba without showing any attempt at using it.

Comment: I like the idea of requiring a motivation but what would be done with this? We trust that the comments are constructive and should be shown to the OP to drive up question quality?

Comment: I suppose Excel formula is convertible with VBA's, wouldn't they, given many names being used interchangeably to indicate similar things : macro, vba, formula, function, excel-vba, excel-formula, etc. Good man Scott answered almost right after my question. So the downvote person either downvoted after the answer was put, or downvoted and flew away with no answer. Either way is not so constructive.

Comment: "We trust that the comments are constructive and should be shown to the OP to drive up question quality"
Yes, I agree, and you and I would never fake. We just don't!
However, other people ... go figure ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a table with your input and desired output:

[image]

Then you can use VLOOKUP to return the desired output:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,E:F,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: To get the desired full string, you can also add "A1&" -> "& before the suggested vlookup formula, such as:    ="A1&" -> "&VLOOKUP(A1,E:F,2,FALSE)